Intuition behind why Rust's io::stdin().read_line() relies on a side effect?
I'm reading the second chapter of the official Rust book as a pretty seasoned python programmer. As you can imagine, its been pretty jarring, but I'm learning.
My specific question is about whether or not there is a good intuitive (or perhaps historical) reason that io::stdin().readline() reads data into a variable as a side effect rather than returning the data and using an assignment.
For example, here is the Rust book's version of the program:
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}

What puzzled me at first is the fact that io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess) is not assigned to any variable, but is manipulating the passed variable directly. Is there a reason why this isn't the more intuitve:
let mut guess = io::stdin()
    .read_line()
    .expect("Failed to read line");

(^^^ this code doesn't work)

The code example which doesn't work relies on the return value of expect(string) - what is the return value of that function?

It returns the number of bytes in the input.

Imagine a simple program which reads a file line by line. There are two ways to write it:
Here's the one where a new string is returned every iteration (hidden in the lines iterator).
use std::fs::*;
use std::io::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("lines.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut i = 1;
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        println!("{i}: {line}");
        i += 1;
    }
    Ok(())
}

And here's the one that has a single line variable.
use std::fs::*;
use std::io::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("lines.txt")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut i = 1;
    let mut line = String::new();
    while reader.read_line(&mut line)? != 0 {
        print!("{i}: {line}");
        line.clear();
        i += 1;
    }
    Ok(())
}

If you were to trace the memory allocations of these two programs, you'd find that the first allocates and deallocates a new string buffer on every iteration. The second, however, only allocates a new buffer whenever a line is longer than the existing buffer.
For some programs, this performance difference actually matters.

This is a C-style API, reused in Linux read syscall, C++ IO buffers, Java's InputStream, Python's file object and many other languages.
There are multiple motivations for externally managed buffer:

performance - allocation of a buffer is quite cheap but not as cheap as a reuse of an existing one. Yes, even with move semantics.
cohesion - allocating buffer within IO operation is not cohesive and is an unnecessary coupling. C-style API decouples resource management and IO.
lifetime management - buffer and the stream can now have independent lifetimes, which is critical, when stream uses an important resource (keeps a file open, for example) or a very large buffer is required occasionally

A seasoned Python programmer should not be surprised by this choice, given that even performance ignorant Python uses similar API for maximum performance.

Reading into a buffer isn't what I am confused by. In python I open(filepath, 'r') and it returns a File object. My confusion is with why they have the read_line function read into its passed parameter.

@RyanFolks Its not about whether a buffer is used or not. Its who owns the buffer. You only get these advantages if the caller owns the buffer. You can't reuse a buffer for example if the method allocates a new one every time.

@user1937198: As I understand, the issue is that, while the function itself makes a buffer within its own scope, as soon as the function ends and returns, it effectively would have to re-create the same buffer for the scope above it? Meaning that it is slightly more efficient to just have the function say "Give me a buffer to write to, and I'll put the stuff directly there.", and avoid the scope-based duplication of the string buffer?

@AlexanderThe1st technically, there is no need to allocate the buffer for the calling code - move semantics and return value optimization could effectively reassign the internal buffer to the external one at virtually no cost. However, the first allocation you mention would still need to happen every time, and that's significant. With external buffer, no allocations happen at all.
